# html Image title alignment

Tags: html, css

I have simple image of red indicator and I put to the image title, the html code is as below:

```
<img alt='' src='imageUrl' title='myExplanation' />
```

The problem is that the title is align to the right, you can see it in the following snapshot:

[image: Title align to the right]

I want the title to align to the left how can I achieve this?

Comment: @ilayzeidman i tried [`your code`](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/tezenep7/). It doesnt seem any wrong in this. Can u share your whole code.

Comment: @Prashant you can see that when the line is not complete it aligns to the right...

Comment: @ilayzeidman not getting ....text is left align

Comment: you right I found the problem see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my browser was in Hebrew version which by default aligns text from right to left I changed my chrome to English version and it is now working! Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 3):

Also you can try some custom tooltip plugins. Like [jquery tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, `title` aligns relative to the position of your mouse pointer. OS or the Browser has control over this feature and you cannot change the default behaviour.

If you want, then create your own `div` element, add the content to it, and then use CSS to align it to the left

```
div.title {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
}
```

..this will float that div to the left side and use more CSS to stylize it.

#### Another way

Another way of doing this functionality is to use a bootstrap, twitter bootstrap would be a good start. It is a framework for CSS, JavaScript and you can use that framework to create the Title tags which are more stylized by the developers and is good for UI and UX too. Try that one if you don't want to create your own from scratch.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Comment: @ilayzeidman, read the answer again. :) If you want to use Bootstrap, use it! :) It is better choice, :) good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
img[title]:hover:after // while hover
```

worked for me

```
    <style>
    img[title]:hover:after {
       content: attr(title);
       border:1px solid #ccc;
       background-color:#aaa;
       color:#f00;
    }
    </style>
```